# Copy MySQL columns from one table to another

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'd like to copy a number of rows from one table to another within phpmyadmin. The table i'm copying from is the `profile` table. The table `user` i'm copying to already exists but the columns do not. I'm attempting the following command in the SQL tab of phpmyadmin.

```
INSERT INTO user 
   (profileImage, 
   skypeName, 
   facebookProfile, 
   twitterProfile, 
   reputation, 
   genderPreference, 
   agePreference, 
   fluentLanguage, 
   desiredLanguage) 

(SELECT profileImage, skypeName, facebookProfile, twitterProfile, reputation, genderPreference, agePreference, fluentLanguage, desiredLanguage FROM profile)
```

For some reason this isn't working out for me. I'm getting an error:

`#1054 - Unknown column 'profileImage' in 'field list'`

`profileImage` exists in the `profile` table, i.e. it is the name of one of my fields

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Have you tried prefixing your table with your database name? `INSERT INTO db.tbl` and `SELECT FROM db2.tbl` ?

Comment: `proileImage` is misspelled, could that be the cause?

Comment: Yes i have, also with no success.

Comment: @RickKuipers Apologies, that was mistyped by me - that's not the problem, edited now

Comment: I think you answered the question yourself: the table exists, but the columns do not. Add the columns manually and run the query again.

Comment: You should first find out why the column does not exist, try to check the spelling or simply just run a SELECT * FROM profile, then after that, do an INSERT if you're sure that the profileImage column is really there.

Comment: or do: CREATE TABLE user SELECT * FROM profile (delete the user table first)

Comment: @ElsonSolano But i'm actually trying to copy the columns themselves including any data that might be in them (in this case the columns have no data as of yet). The idea being to save me from having to create all the same fields again in a different table

Comment: @DirkMcQuickly But the `user` table already exists?

Comment: @garethdn When there is no data in the table, first remove it.

Comment: @DirkMcQuickly My `user` table already contains data

Comment: @garethdn I don't understand it. So you do have columns in the user table, just not the 'profileImage' etc?

Comment: @DirkMcQuickly Correct - i want to add MORE columns from another table to the `user` table

Comment: @garethdn then manually add the columns...

Comment: I actually get "Unexpected token. (near "(" at position...)" if I put the second part of the statement in brackets. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is `#1054 - Unknown column 'proileImage' in 'field list'` then, simply, that column *doesn't* exist in either (or both) your profile or your user table.

Just run the select part of the query, ie. 
`SELECT profileImage, skypeName, facebookProfile, twitterProfile, reputation, genderPreference, agePreference, fluentLanguage, desiredLanguage FROM profile`

Does that work?

If so, are you sure `profileImage` exists in the user table?

Comment: When running your query i get `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0003 sec )`. `profileImage` does not exist in the `user` table, i thought my SQL query would create the those columns when copying them from the `profile` table?

Comment: Ah no, not at all. You'll have to create those columns first.

Comment: Oh right, perhaps i was expecting too much from MySQL! So if i had 100 columns in table X that i wanted to copy to table Y, i'd have to create all those columns in table Y before i could copy the data from those columns in table X?

Comment: Yes. I don't *think* you can do so programmatically in MySQL itself (but it's perhaps worth a new question), but you could certainly do so with php.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the structure of the table 1 to table 2 in phpmyadmin and can then run query to copy certain rows from table 1 to table 2.